# Unable to get request timeout response using node.js

Tags: node.js, request, timeout

I am trying to set the timeout values inside `request` module of node.js but as per the given time its not returning the response. I am explaining my code below.

```
postRequestOptions.url = `${nsoObj.protocol}://${nsoObj.ipAddress}:${nsoObj.httpPortNbr}/jsonrpc`;
    postRequestOptions.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    postRequestOptions.body = {
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      id: 1,
      method: 'login',
      timeout: 5000,
      params: {
        user: nsoObj.userName,
        passwd: nsoObj.password
      }
    };

    request(postRequestOptions, (error, response, loginResponse) => {
      console.log('\n error: ', error);
      console.log('\n loginResponse: ', loginResponse);

      if (error || !loginResponse.id) {
        responseObj = {
          status : 'error',
          msg : `Error occurred while performing Login into "${nsoObj.nsoNickName}"  Instance. ${error}`,
          body : null
        };
        reject(responseObj);
      } else {
        loginResponse.sessionId = response.headers['set-cookie'][0];
        responseObj = {
          status : 'success',
          msg : `Successfully performing Login into "${nsoObj.nsoNickName}"  Instance`,
          body : loginResponse
        };
        resolve(responseObj);
      }
    });
  });
```

Here I am using `request` module of `node.js` and set timeout of `5ms`. But When I am running this its taking 2min to sent back the timeout error response.

Here I need if this request could not sent back the response within `5 milisecond` then it should return the timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

delete timeout from body and using `postRequestOptions.timeout = 5000;` so do like this:

```
postRequestOptions.url = `${nsoObj.protocol}://${nsoObj.ipAddress}:${nsoObj.httpPortNbr}/jsonrpc`;
    postRequestOptions.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    postRequestOptions.body = {
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      id: 1,
      method: 'login',
      params: {
        user: nsoObj.userName,
        passwd: nsoObj.password
      }
    };
    postRequestOptions.timeout = 5000;//should be outside the body
    request(postRequestOptions, (error, response, loginResponse) => {
      console.log('\n error: ', error);
      console.log('\n loginResponse: ', loginResponse);

      if (error || !loginResponse.id) {
        responseObj = {
          status : 'error',
          msg : `Error occurred while performing Login into "${nsoObj.nsoNickName}"  Instance. ${error}`,
          body : null
        };
        reject(responseObj);
      } else {
        loginResponse.sessionId = response.headers['set-cookie'][0];
        responseObj = {
          status : 'success',
          msg : `Successfully performing Login into "${nsoObj.nsoNickName}"  Instance`,
          body : loginResponse
        };
        resolve(responseObj);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I just added as per you but same issue. Its taking around 2min.

Comment: I think, your request is completely in correct, why the method is login?

Comment: No, its giving right result in positive test case. This is json rpc call.

Comment: can you send me the link of module in npm?

Comment: its the same request module in npm. now I am trying `connect-timeout` module.

Comment: based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rpc-2.0 did you write your code?

Comment: check this one `https://www.edureka.co/community/22880/nodejs-post-request-over-json-rpc`.

Comment: with this code  dose your server response correctly??? can you login correctly?

Comment: yes, I told for positive test case its working as expected but there is one case where I need the timeout error.